# How to convert JSON to URL params string as per my expected value?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, url, parameters

I am working on an angular project. For a method getting a response JSON to convert stringify and POST a body to an API is done. Now the problem is for another one function I should send this value as a URL parameter I tried some ways but didn't get expected result. Please find the below codes and help me out. Thanks

Here is my JSON format value

```
const bodyJSON = [{FullPackageIDs:[11,7],
                    PartialPkg:[
                        {PackageID:4,
                            FormsList:[
                                {Form_Name:"Form name One"},
                                {Form_Name:"Form name Two"}]},
                        {PackageID:6,
                            FormsList:[
                                {Form_Name:"Form name Three"},
                                {Form_Name:"Form name Four"},
                                {Form_Name:"Form name Five"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }]
```

My expected URL string value like below

```
http://localhost:4200/DownloadPackage?FullPackageIDs[0]=11&FullPackageIDs[1]=7&PartialPkg[0].PackageID=4&PartialPkg[0].FormsList[0].Form_Name=Form name One&PartialPkg[0].FormsList[1].Form_Name=Form name Two&PartialPkg[1].PackageID=6&PartialPkg[0].FormsList[0].Form_Name=Form name Three&PartialPkg[1].FormsList[1].Form_Name=Form name Four&PartialPkg[2].FormsList[2].Form_Name=Form name Five
```

I tried via forloop but didnt get expected result. Here is the code for what I tried.

```
for (let i = 0; i < getSelectedId.length; i++) {
  fullPackageParams = `${fullPackageParams}FullPackageIDs[${i}]=${getSelectedId[i]}&`;
  for (let j = 0; j < getPartialId.length; j++) {
    // const getPartialName = this.partialPackage.map(res => res[i].FormsList);
    const getPartialName = getPartialId[j].FormsList;

    partialPackageIDParams = `${partialPackageIDParams}PartialPkg[${j}].PackageID=${getPartialId[j].PackageID}&`;

    for (let index = 0; index < getPartialName.length; index++) {
      partialPackageNameParams = `PartialPkg[${index}].FormsList[${index}].Form_Name=${getPartialName[index].Form_Name}&`;
    }
  }
}
console.log('params for full packages', fullPackageParams + partialPackageIDParams + partialPackageNameParams);
```

Comment: Hi, why not send the json in body instead of query params?

Comment: Yes. It's the easiest way, But here requirement is should send a URL request only :(

Answer (score 0):

even if it seems kinda strange to me that you need to pass all of those params using query, you can try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r5uvcnae/)

it just uses ES6 map, reduce functions to create your query string

```
let URLQuery = bodyJSON.map(value => {
    const packageIDs = value.FullPackageIDs.map((v, i) => `FullPackageIDs[${i}]=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`);
    const partialPkgs = value.PartialPkg.map((v, i) => {
        const startKey = `PartialPkg[${i}]`;
        return [
            `${startKey}.PackageID=${v.PackageID}`
        ].concat(
            v.FormsList.map((v, i) => `${startKey}.FormsList[${i}].Form_Name=${encodeURIComponent(v.Form_Name)}`)
        );
    }).reduce((arr, v) => {
        return arr.concat(v)
    }, []);

    return packageIDs.concat(partialPkgs);
}).reduce((arr, v) => {
    return arr.concat(v);
}, []).join("&");

const fullURL = `https://example.com?${URLQuery}`;
```